# Xamarin forms circular slider

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I want to create like this in xamarin forms. How to implement this?

[image: circular slider]

Xamarin forms create circular scroll view in both android and ios.  I have checked with knobcontrol but i have problem with that.

Comment: https://github.com/xabre/Xamarin-CircularSlider-SeekArc may help you.

Comment: What's the exact problem did you meet?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to go for syncfusion nuget package if you want something that will be kept updated.

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/circular-gauge/header